# AttributeError at /login/ type object 'super' has no attribute 'save'

Tags: python-3.x

Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/?next=/post/new/
Django Version: 2.1.4
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:
type object 'super' has no attribute 'save'
Exception Location: C:\Users\User\Desktop\progetti\django_project\users\models.py in save, line 14

---

this error happen when i insert LoginRequiredMixin in this class in views.py

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ------
    path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    ------
]
```

this is models.py that refers to user:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', 
    upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self):
        super.save()
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
def save(self):
    super.save()
```

You need to *call* `super`, ie:

```
def save(self):
    super().save()
```

Also, `Model.save()` can takes quite a few arguments, that you need to both accept and pass to the `super().save()` call, so the correct implementation is:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And finally, I would definitly not use `Model.save()` to process the image - this should be done in the form to avoid executing this code over and over each time the model is saved.

Comment: Solved. Thanks!

Comment: @GiovanniCiquera then you may want to accept (and eventually upvote) my answer ;-)